# Return object in python

Tags: python, object

I have a code:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(response, htmlparser)
result = tree.xpath(xpath)
# result return [<Element div at 0x2d903a0>]
# I want to view html string
```

I think result is object. How can view result structure to can access return value that I need?

When I code python. I usually get return like <... at 0x325dc>. I don't know what value in <... at 0x325dc>. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

From http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

> xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(element, encoding="us-ascii",
>   method="xml") Generates a string representation of an XML element,
>   including all subelements. element is an Element instance. encoding
>   [1] is the output encoding (default is US-ASCII). method is either
>   "xml", "html" or "text" (default is "xml"). Returns an encoded string
>   containing the XML data.

Know your documentation.

Comment: Tks. But When I code python. I usually get return like <... at 0x325dc>. I don't know what value in <... at 0x325dc>. How can I resolve it?

Comment: Sorry, but I mean It is not in this library. I usually see it in many librarys. And I want know what is in <... at 0x325dc>. I think if in python have any function like var_dump() in php, It can resolve my problem.

Comment: The output clearly tells you that you have a Python list. And iterating for a listing and introspecting the item is straight forward. In doubt use the inspect module or the Python pdb debugger.

Comment: I will try with Python pdb debugger. But I think if it only python list. We can use pprint with depth to view data inside it. anw, tks.